# How to execute js code through Appium on React native

Tags: react-native, appium

We used to have a Cordova app that, when running on Appium, we could switch to Webview and execute JS commands using execute_script.

I would like to do the same thing on React Native to run some JS code (e.g., exposing a function on global or running something like console.disableYellowBox = true;). However, appium does not shows a Webview context to switch to and it seems to me the execute_script on native app context doesn't work.

Is there a way of doing a similar thing on RN client?

Answer (score 0):

For ReactNative application there is no Webview context as RN is interpreted as **NATIVE_APP** one.

For finding elements its more interesting: there is no way to set `resource-id` for Android.

However you can set `accessibilityLabel` for your Views in React Native app and search for it like:

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId(accessibilityLabel)
```

Should work for both iOS/Android. Basically you should right your tests like you test Native app, not a Hybrid one.
And of course, you can use Xpath to search by text, but that I strongly do not recommend to do.

Comment: Well, finding elements is not exactly the issue. What I'm asking is how to make a js call, e.g., global.setUpMyTest();

Comment: Since RN app is interpreted as Native app by Appium, thats why you don't see WebView context. And that means you cannot use JavascriptExecutor, cause its not web components, but Android/iOS ones (depending where you built your Rn app)